# ARKit – ARCoachingOverlayView Spanish localization

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, arquicklook

[image]

Is there a way to use Spanish localization instead of English in ARCoachingOverlayView?

```
let overlay = ARCoachingOverlayView()
overlay.delegate = self                      // ARCoachingOverlayViewDelegate?

overlay.activatesAutomatically = false
overlay.session = self.arSession
overlay.goal = .anyPlane
self.addSubview(overlay)
```

P.S. I need Spanish localisation in iOS app. I know that there's working language localization when we use `Apple Measure` iOS app, or `ARQuickLook`/`ARCoachingOverlayView` app in Safari.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this, @AndyJazz? Not working for me in Xcode 14.0.1/iOS 16.1.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

ARCoachingoverlayview localization can be done by localizing the storyboard
when you add the localizing from the build menu it gets Localised text auto.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DevSn, but this doesn't work for ARCoachingOverlayView.